# export to excel sheet using knockout, javascript and durandal

Tags: javascript, ios, html, excel, durandal

I am using `knockout, javascript and durandal` to build an application which i will convert to `IOS` application using phone gap. I am fairly new to the stuff. I am able to code the other modules but I am stuck at the export to excel facility. As any device like ipad,iphone etc which have IOS, does not support excel. So, how can i go about it. What should I refer. Please help as i am new and dont know what to look for which will help me in solving the problem.

I found the code online. It exports the table to excel. If i use this and convert the html application to native IOS, will the excel functionality work.?

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

Thanks

Comment: How would you convert a JavaScript app to Objective C and expect for anything to work?

Comment: @PWKad : using phone gap.

Comment: If native iOS doesn't have Excel then how would you want the Excel functionality to work?  I believe you should change this question to remove Durandal and HTML5 as this has nothing to do with either of those technologies and instead tag PhoneGap or Cordova or w/e it's called.  Also look up exporting to CSV with JavaScript instead of exporting to Excel.